# Retrieve the record using Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm having spring data jpa repository.I the entity contain primary key id int and ipaddress string. The table contain only 1 record at a time otherwise null.
How do i retrieve the record using JPA , if it is not found return null.

```
        @Repository
        public interface IpConfigRepository extends   JpaRepository<IpConfig, Integer> {
         //
         IpConfig findIpConfig();
        }
```

Comment: Use `findAll()` and manage the null conversion yourself in your service, or write a query.

Answer (score 0):

According to the naming convention, you should define the method with the name `findById(Integer id)` ( assume the Id is the primary key )

Comment: I don't want to do it like passing primary key. If some how the primary key was changed then i have to change the code again.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a class A as shown below

```
   class A{
       private int id;
       private String data;

       // getters and setters

   }
```

You can now search the items by the following ways.

```
public interface ARepo extends JpaRepository<A,Integer>{

  // get all the records from table. 
  List<A> findAll();

  // find record by id
  A findById(int id);

  // find record by data
  A findByData(String data);

  // find by date created or updated
  A findByDateCreated(Date date);

  // custom query method to select only one record from table
  @Query("SELECT * FROM a limit 1;")
  A findRecord();



}
```

Comment: showing `antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: *`

Comment: Change `@Query("SELECT * FROM a limit 1;")` to `@Query("SELECT a FROM A a limit 1;")` and it should work.

Comment: you can do as mentioned by @sz4b0lcs or you can define table name using `@Table(name="a")` in your entity/domain class to name the table formed in database